# Autofilter for 4 criterias in a single column using excel vba

Tags: vba, excel

[i need this kind of filtered data in excel](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UUgsy.png)I need to filter 4 Criteria in one column. Used autofilter but it didn't work.it work's only for 2 Criteria.
[image: The code that I have used and didn't worked]

Please give a solution for this issue.

P.S: I am a beginner in Excel Vba.

Comment: I can only suggest to bring your data to standart view, which is table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is easier to re-distribute your data, but to use AutoFIlter you can reduce **4** criteria to **1** criteria by applying a "helper" column.

The helper column will contain the formula:

```
=IF(OR(ISNUMBER(FIND("Number",A2)),ISNUMBER(FIND("Name",A2)),ISNUMBER(FIND("Street",A2)),ISNUMBER(FIND("Address",A2))),"Display","Hide")
```

We can then filter on the "helper".  Before:

[image]

The code:

```
Sub User()
    Dim N As Long, r1 As Range, r2 As Range
    Dim s As String

    N = Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    Range("B1").Value = "helper"
    Set r1 = Range("B2:B" & N)
    s = "=IF(OR(ISNUMBER(FIND(""Number"",A2)),ISNUMBER(FIND(""Name"",A2)),ISNUMBER(FIND(""Street"",A2)),ISNUMBER(FIND(""Address"",A2))),""Display"",""Hide"")"
    r1.Formula = s

    With Range("A:B")
        .AutoFilter
        .AutoFilter Field:=2, Criteria1:="Display"
    End With
End Sub
```

and after:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

AutoFilter is limited to 2 criteria with wildcards (* or ?)

The 2 versions below will allow you to specify as many wildcards as you need

---

.

**Version 1** - Loops through each wildcard applying the AutoFliter and combining the visible ranges

---

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub FilterRows3WildAF()      '(Optional ByVal showAll As Boolean = False)

    Const FILTER_COL = "A"
    Const WILDCARDS = "Name Street Address Number"  'cell starts with these 4 words

    Dim ws As Worksheet, wild As Variant, lr As Long, toShow As Range, itm As Variant

    Set ws = ActiveSheet
    wild = Split(WILDCARDS) 'will search for cells starting with: Name*, then Street*, etc
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    ws.Rows.Hidden = False

    With ws.Range(ws.Cells(1), ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, FILTER_COL).End(xlUp))
        lr = .Rows.Count
        Set toShow = .Cells(lr + 1, FILTER_COL)
        For Each itm In wild
            .AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:=itm & "*", Operator:=xlFilterValues
            If .SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Cells.CountLarge > 1 Then
                Set toShow = Union(toShow, .Offset(1).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible))
            End If
        Next
        .AutoFilter
        .Rows.Hidden = True
        toShow.EntireRow.Hidden = False
    End With
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

---

.

**Version 2** - Loops through each cell, checking with InStr() if the wildcard exists

---

```
Public Sub FilterRows3WildInstr()   '(Optional ByVal showAll As Boolean = False)

    Const FILTER_COL = "A"
    Const WILDCARDS = "Name Street Address Number"  'cell starts with these 4 words

    Dim ws As Worksheet, wild As Variant, lr As Long, arr As Variant
    Dim toHide As Range, r As Long, itm As Variant, found As Boolean

    Set ws = ActiveSheet
    wild = Split(WILDCARDS) 'will search for cells starting with: Name*, then Street*, etc
    ws.Rows.Hidden = False

    With ws.Range(ws.Cells(1), ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, FILTER_COL).End(xlUp))
        lr = .Rows.Count
        arr = .Value2
        Set toHide = .Cells(lr + 1, FILTER_COL)
        For r = 1 To UBound(arr)
            For Each itm In wild
                found = InStr(1, arr(r, 1), itm) > 0
                If found Then Exit For
            Next
            If Not found Then Set toHide = Union(toHide, .Cells(r, FILTER_COL))
        Next
        toHide.EntireRow.Hidden = True: .Rows(lr + 1).Hidden = False
    End With
End Sub
```